# Why Firefox incorrectly displays the table with colspan and rowspan?

Tags: firefox, html-table

The table is displayed well in Chrome and Opera, and not at all in Firefox ... How can I fix it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzfV7.jpg)

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/Hamsterman/6zth1mjv/

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Basically don't use a table to do this. I'm surprised that works at all TBH. You have all sorts of craziness going on there. You'll be much better off using flow and CSS to achieve what you want. `<table>` should be used for **tabular data** <Full stop> not layout and certainly not complicated layout like your attempting here

Comment: the only good reason I can see for this is your attempting to embed this in an email?